# Estimation of bode plot of closed loop system based on open loop characteristics

Tags: control, bode-plot, loop-gain, closed-loop

I just got an exam back in which I did the error of not drawing the phase part of the bode plot of a closed loop system. The question sparked, how does one estimate the shape of the phase plot of a closed loop system based on the open loop characteristics?

Through exercices and trial I noticed that, just like the gain, the phase tends to stay constant at 0° until near the bandwidth frequency at which it decreases down to -180° but, apart from an assumption, is it possible to do this analitically?

The question was "Approximate the closed loop Bode diagram"

[image: Exercice I had to solve]

Edit: To clarify, my casehas unity negative feedback.

Comment: Why don't you post the actual problem you had to solve?

Comment: No - when you have no other information than the loop gain, it is not possible to know the closed-loop response.

Comment: @Andyaka I added the problem but I'm looking for the general solution for any open/closed loop system

Comment: @LvW Even with the open loop phase?

Comment: Example: When the loop gain is A*B we do not know if the closed-loop gain is A/(1+AB) or AB/(1+AB). In the 1st case, the forward path is "A" with B in the feedback path; in the second case the forward path is "AB" with 100% feedback.

Comment: @LvW Alright I get what you're saying, in this module we always defined the open loop as the forward gain times the feedback gain. Thanks for clarifying though,

Comment: @Luka What is "feedback gain"? The loop gain always is "forward gain times feedback factor". However, sometimes the feedback factor is unity and sometimes B (see my example above).

Comment: @LvW I meant the feedback factor as feedback gain, I don't know which term is the most exact. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observations are partially correct. Let us assume that open loop transfer function \$L(s)\$ is known. The closed loop transfer function \$T(s)\$ from reference to output in case of unit feedback is then given by
$$T(s) = \frac{L(s)}{1 + L(s)}.$$
For frequencies where \$|L(s)| >> 1\$ we get
$$T(s) = \frac{L(s)}{1 + L(s)} \approx \frac{L(s)}{L(s)} = 1.$$
Similiarly,we get for \$|L(s)| << 1\$
$$T(s) = \frac{L(s)}{1 + L(s)} \approx \frac{L(s)}{1} = L(s).$$
For \$|L(s)| \approx 1\$ the behaviour is difficult to approximate (one could probably make use of the first order behaviour of \$L\$ around crossover frequency as is common in control system design due to stability reasons and other). The approximations provide insight into common design rules when shaping the open loop transfer function for good reference following.

1.) We want large gain |L| over the relevant frequency ranges of our reference signal

2.) We want small gain |L| over frequency ranges where noise might be a problem.

to name a few. I recommend taking a look at "Multivariable feedback control" by Skogestad if you have access to it. The case of non unit feedback can be handled in a similiar manner.

Comment: @Yggdrasil You should mention that your answer covers only the special case with unity negative feedback.

Comment: Okey, since 1 has no phase, when well below the crossover frequency the phase is 0° and when well above it is 180°+. For the region around it I guess that an approximation by "connecting the lines" would be sufficient. Thanks!